# REST web service jpa update statement

Tags: java, sql, web-services, rest, jpa

I am working on an application that helps the user check his `"bank accounts"` and transfering from an account to an other through the application. I am using a rest web service to do the sql operations. And I am having a problem in the function that transfer from one account to the other. This method should update the table `"compte"` (bank account) that contains the following columns : `"id"` , `"currencyId"` , `"clientId"` , `"montant"` (amount ).

```
@GET
@Path("transaction/{id1}/{id2}/{amount}")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public String  Transfer(@PathParam("id1") String compte1 ,@PathParam("id2") String compte2,@PathParam("amount")  int amount ) {
    Compte c1 = new Compte();
    c1.setId(compte1);
    c1=(Compte) (em.createQuery("select montant from Compte where id=:id").setParameter("id", c1).getSingleResult());
    c1.setMontant(c1.getMontant()-amount);
    Query query1=em.createQuery("update compte set montant=:montantVal where compte.id=:compte1");
    query1.setParameter("montantVal", c1);
    query1.setParameter("compte1", c1);
    query1.executeUpdate();

    Compte c2 = new Compte();
    c2.setId(compte2);
    c2.setMontant(em.createQuery("select montant from compte where id=:id").setParameter("id", c2).getFirstResult());
    c2.setMontant(c2.getMontant()+amount);
    Query query2=em.createQuery("update compte set montant=:montantVal where compte.id=':compte2'");
    query2.setParameter("montantVal", c2);
    query2.setParameter("compte2", c2);
    query2.executeUpdate();
```

This code is giving the following error :

```
Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select montant from Compte where id=:id]. 
[27, 27] An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration.
```

Comment: Sounds unreliable for me. you may need to begin a transaction and do the whole process by the transaction. also the command would be like this `select montant from Compte c where c.id=:id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is `em.createQuery` use JPQL string statement so it should be

```
em.createQuery("select c.montant from Compte c where c.id=:id")
```

Where Compte is the name of the class, although it is not clear on your port the name of your entities I assume you have something like this.

```
@Entity
public class Compte{
  @Id
  private int id;
  private int currencyId;
  private double montant;
}
```

remember JPQL use the name of the entities and properties not the name of the tables and columns.

> An identification variable must be provided for a range variable
>   declaration.

Is defined as c in the query above.